# Serial.Read in the setup of an Arduino code?

Tags: arduino, arduino-due

Is it possible to perform a Serial.Read in the Setup area of an Arduino code? I need my main loop to be fast and don't want it to be slowed down by a piece of code that only has to run once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put Serial.read() in the setup() function.  Be sure that you put it after Serial.begin().  Since Serial.read() is "non-blocking" you will need to put some additional code to loop and wait for something to read.  Serial.read() returns -1 if there is no data waiting in the serial input buffer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is Serial.Read() function example:- [Click](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Read)

And this one is Serial Event example:- [Click](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SerialEvent)

Comment: I cannot see the answer to Lego man's question in that link. BTW, the answer is 'possible, but not useful'. You need a loop anyway to wait for any incoming text after Serial.begin() ( and eventually another loop ** while (!Serial() ) {} ** ) For loops, you best use the predeclared loop() function.